# Replace empty src with image url - JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a page with multiple images, all with class `.listImage`

```
<img src="/path/to/image1.png" class="listImage">
<img src="/path/to/image2.png" class="listImage">
<img src="" class="listImage">
<img src="/path/to/image3.png" class="listImage">
```

On some occasions these may actually not have a `.src` value, therefore I want to replace any that don't with a dummy image.

Here's what I'm trying but doesn't work for some reason:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('.listImage').each(function () {
        if (this.src.length == 0) {
            $(this).attr('src','/images/img_blank.png');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this using [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$().ready(function () {
    $('.listImage[src=""]').attr('src','/images/img_blank.png');
});
```

Comment: **+1** Doesn't select un-needed `<a>`, perfect =)

Comment: Awesome - how to cut 5 lines to 1 - great lesson, thanks

Comment: So using the attribute selector in fact adds the if in the same line, excellent!

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Yeah, here's documentation on attribute-equals-selector http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem but . . .

change `$()` to `$(document)`

did that fix it?

if not try . . .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.listImage').each(function () {
        if($(this).attr("src") == "#") {
            $(this).attr('src','/images/img_blank.png');
        }
    });
});
```

Change the empty `src` attribute value to `#`

Answer (score 0):

Use this condition

```
if (this.attr("src").length == 0) {
```

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.listImage').each(function () {
    if (this.attr("src").length == 0) {
        $(this).attr('src','/images/img_blank.png');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$('.listImage').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('src') == '') {
        $(this).attr('src','/images/img_blank.png');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.listImage').each(function (index,value) {
        if ($(value).attr('src')=='') {
            $(value).attr('src','notfound.png');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are using attribute like data-src instead src. this would work:

```
$('.listImage').each(function () {
    if (!hasAttr('src')) {
     temp_attr = $(this).attr('data-src'); //temporary attribute for your src

        $(this).attr('src',temp_attr); //Create src attribute with your value

    $(this).removeAttr('data-src'); //remove temporary attribute to clean up stuff.
    }
});
```

from above code, in case you are using img tag like this:

`<img data-src="image.png">`

will convert to img tag with src attribute like this:

`<img src="image.png">`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.listImage').each(function (index,i) {
        alert(index)
        if ($(".listImage:eq("+index+")").attr("src").length == 0) {
                $(".listImage:eq("+index+")").attr('src','/images/img_blank.png');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple way: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/WgF5H/1/

```
$('.listImage[src=""]').attr('src', '/images/img_blank.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also see this code

```
$('.listImage').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("src")=="") {
        $(this).attr('src','/images/img_blank.png');
    }
});
```